# How to limit the depth of embedded referenced entities

Tags: entities

Using Drupal 9 or 10
Using a node type Page with one entity reference field, which is displayed as rendered entity, displaying the same Page content type.

When viewing a page, how do I prevent the page from having endless nested pages in it, leading to infinite loading?
I like to limit the nesting to 4 levels deep.

Comment: What do you mean endless nested pages? You can set field cardinality to 4. If you are trying to create hierarchy, I suggest using the menu system. Using regular reference fields does not necessarily imply hierarchy at all (outside of Taxonomy or Menu Links, because it has support for that).

Comment: What I mean is that when a page display includes a fully rendered other page (in its entity reference field) which again has the same entity reference field thus fully rendered third page, that third page also has a fully rendered fourth page etc etc then there is infinite loading of pages. I want to prevent the infinite loading of nested pages from happening, but want to allow e.g. 4 nested pages to be displayed in each other.

Comment: My guess is you'll need to create a custom field formatter for you entity reference field.

Comment: This module might be a good direction for you: [Custom Formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_formatters)